# ElementName bindings not working reliably - suspected dispatcher race condition

Tags: wpf, data-binding, itemscontrol, dispatcher

[Download repro project](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0By4aHfGkOltCaE1vc2pqRXluWm8)

**Edit**

The solution working sometimes completely threw me off my initial wondering why this is working in the first place. After all, the items aren't part of the Visual tree. In the end, it makes total sense:

- The buttons in that collection aren't in the visual tree and thus element bindings don't work.
- Applying the templates puts them into the visual tree and binding, if applied at this time, start working.
- This confirms the suspected race condition.

A colleague of mine did some extended debugging that showed the issue as well - in the cases the binding succeeded, OnApplyBinding was invoked first. So using the collection without adjusting the logical tree was simply flawed.

Thanks for the replies that put back on the right track!

---

**Original Post**

I have a view control that exposes an ObservableCollection, My view can contain arbitrary elements, e.g. buttons. Note the **ElementName** binding on the button:

```
<local:ViperView>    
    <local:ViperView.MenuItems>
        <Button Content="{Binding ElementName=btn, Path=Content}" />
    </local:ViperView.MenuItems>

    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="btn" Content="HELLO WORLD" />
    </Grid>
</local:ViperView>
```

The control's ControlTemplate just renders the content using an ItemsControl:

```
<ControlTemplate ...
...

    <ItemsControl
        x:Name="PART_NavigationMenuItemsHost"
        ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
 </ControlTemplate>
```

The view above is assigned to the ActiveView property of my main view model. The main window just displays the view via data binding.

Now the problem: The ElementName binding **within** that view doesn't work reliably if the view is not immediately assigned to the view model after it's creation.

[image]

ElementName bindings work like this:

```
MainViewModel.ActiveView = new ViperView();
```

ElementName bindings works ***sometimes*** using normal priority:

```
var view = new ViperView();
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => MainViewModel.ActiveView  view);
```

ElementName binding ***always fails*** if the view model property is set with low priority:

```
var view = new ViperView();
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, () => MainViewModel.ActiveView = view);
```

ElementName binding ***sometimes*** works if the property is set from a worker thread (Binding engine marshalls back to the UI thread):

```
var view = new ViperView();
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => MainViewModel.ActiveView = view);
```

ElementName binding ***always fails*** if the worker thread has a delay:

```
var view = new ViperView();
var view = new ViperView();
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
{
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    MainViewModel.ActiveView = view;
});
```

I don't have an answer to this. It appears to be related to timings. For example, if I add a short Thread.Sleep to the Task sample above, this *always* causes the bindings to break, while without the sleep, it only sometimes breaks.

This is quite the show stopper for me - any pointer are appreciated...

Thanks for your advice
Philipp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the ElementName binding in part fails before the buttons in the sample are even added to the collection of the parent view, there's not much I can do to intercept the bindings. A slightly dirty workaround would be to just refresh the bindings in those controls once the template has been applied and the visual tree established:

Fron OnApplyTemplate, invoke:

```
internal static class BindingUtil
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Recursively resets all ElementName bindings on the submitted object
    /// and its children.
    /// </summary>
    public static void ResetElementNameBindings(this DependencyObject obj)
    {
        IEnumerable boundProperties = obj.GetDataBoundProperties();
        foreach (DependencyProperty dp in boundProperties)
        {
            Binding binding = BindingOperations.GetBinding(obj, dp);
            if (binding != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(binding.ElementName)) //binding itself should never be null, but anyway
            {
                //just updating source and/or target doesn’t do the trick – reset the binding
                BindingOperations.ClearBinding(obj, dp);
                BindingOperations.SetBinding(obj, dp, binding);
            }
        }

        int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj);
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            //process child items recursively
            DependencyObject childObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);
            ResetElementNameBindings(childObject);
        }
    }


    public static IEnumerable GetDataBoundProperties(this DependencyObject element)
    {
        LocalValueEnumerator lve = element.GetLocalValueEnumerator();

        while (lve.MoveNext())
        {
            LocalValueEntry entry = lve.Current;
            if (BindingOperations.IsDataBound(element, entry.Property))
            {
                yield return entry.Property;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Another fix, and probably preferable, would be to change the logical tree at runtime. Adding the code below to my view solves the issue, too:

```
public class ViperView : ContentControl
{
    private readonly ObservableCollection<object> menuItems = new ObservableCollection<object>();

    public ObservableCollection<object> NavigationMenuItems
    {
        get { return menuItems; }
    }


    public ViperView()
    {
        NavigationMenuItems.CollectionChanged += OnMenuItemsChanged;
    }

    private void OnMenuItemsChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewItems != null)
        {
            foreach (var newItem in e.NewItems)
            {
                AddLogicalChild(newItem);
            }
        }
    }

    protected override IEnumerator LogicalChildren
    {
        get
        {
            yield return this.Content;
            foreach (var mi in NavigationMenuItems)
            {
                yield return mi;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, `ElementName` binding is not updated at any time: it'll only bind to the property once and then stop updating.
This could explain your problem here: the first binding will happen (or won't) depending on the timestamp.

There is a change you can fix it by specifying the `UpdateSourceTrigger` property for the binding:

```
<Button Content="{Binding ElementName=btn, Path=Content, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

This will make sure your binding gets updated every time btn.Content is updated.

Hope this works =)

Comment: As far I know, you're wrong :P. That binding is "PropertyChanged" by default.

Comment: @ChrisDD: You are both wrong. 1. `UpdateSourceTrigger` is meaningless for a control which does not on *its own* change the property value. 2. `UpdateSourceTrigger` is also meaningless if the binding is not `TwoWay` or `OneWayToSource`, which it isn't either in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I can't quite explain why the first option works. However I can explain why the other ones wont work.

Okay, first of all, ElementName can only work when elements are in the same visual tree. Notice that NavigationButtonItems are seperate from the actual content of ViperView.

Thus say you do:

```
<Button Content="{Binding ActualWidth, 
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=WpfApplication2:ViperView}}" />
```

(it's part of NavigationButtonItems). Now if the NavigationButtonItems and ViperView items are not blended into one(blending to one visual tree happens in ControlTemplate), then this binding would fail, and STAY as failed.

Now say the visual tree happens to be ONE as the binding is happening, then the binding will succeed and everything is nice.

Note that blending into one visual tree happens when you render the content, eg do: 
dc.ActiveScreen = viperview;

Here is a quick example to demonstrate how you can do it little better:

```
  <Button

            Background="Purple"
            Width="100"
            Height="20"
             >
            <Button.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Button">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsReady}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding ActualWidth, 
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=WpfApplication2:ViperView}}" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
        </Button>
```

IsReady property should be in viewModel and it essentially tells that "YES, everything is rendered as one visual tree now, you can apply bindings."

If you do the IsReady trick, the ActualWidth will start working:

```
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                              {
                                  Thread.Sleep(10);
                                  dc.ActiveScreen = view;
                                  //ps you might need to force wpf finish with  rendering here. like use Application.DoEvents()
                                  dc.IsReady = true;//force bindings since everything is one now.
                              });
```

Let me know if you need clarifications.

Comment: I was surprised, too that ElementBindings were working in the first place in the old, synchronously working shell, but they did so reliably. My problem is that I can't just change the existing button - the sample is a dumbed down version of a rather complex application architecture that provides an integration layer for hundreds of views - which contain bindings in part. I also can't ask devs to create bindings as complex as this. I guess, for new screens, I should just make that Items collection an ItemsControl (or custom items control) in the first place so it *is* part of the visual tree.